# Degree centrality modified for a specific situation

Tags: neo4j

I created a query which will match for a node the incoming degree to be 0 and the outgoing degree to be different than 0. Like this, I can identify the root diseases (diseases which have no ancestors) in my graph.

I have 2 types of relationships in my graph: HAS_CHILD( as the direct descendant of a disease) and HAS_DESCENDANT(as a descendant of a disease)

```
MATCH (u:Disease) where size((u)<-[:HAS_CHILD|HAS_DESCENDANT]-())=0  and size((u)-[:HAS_DESCENDANT]->())<>0 RETURN u.prefered_name, size((u)-[:HAS_CHILD]->()) AS Parent_of,size((u)<-[:HAS_CHILD]-()) AS Children_of ORDER BY size((u)-[:HAS_CHILD]->());
```

The first 4 result of this query shows both degrees 0, but I specified that one of the degrees should be different than 0. Why is giving me this weird result?[image: the result of the query, not what expected]

I expect that the query will show me the result without including the first 4 records. when I review the query I cannot find any mistake, in my opinion, it should work

Comment: I perform the same query only changing the size((u)-[:HAS_DESCENDANT]->())<>0 to size((u)-[:HAS_CHILD]->())<>0 and in this case everything works how I expect

Comment: I need both queries to work as expected to be able to identify all aggregators nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The first 4 result of this query shows both degrees 0, but I specified
>   that one of the degrees should be different than 0. Why is giving me
>   this weird result?

check your query, you specified for `HAS_DESCENDANT`

```
size((u)-[:HAS_DESCENDANT]->())<>0
```

but in return statement

```
 size((u)-[:HAS_CHILD]->()) AS Parent_of
```

you are getting result for `HAS_CHILD`

Comment: Thank you for noticing my error. This helped a lot!